# How to disable items limit on category page in Joomla K2?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

The website I'm working on uses component K2 for Joomla 2.5. Just 10 items [articles] are displayed on category page inside of #itemListLeading div and 10 inside of #itemListPrimary. How can I disable this limit and display all the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may echo all the items on the category page with direct query to MySQL without the limit of #itemListLeading. See [How to get Joomla K2 item as object on category page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295729/how-to-get-joomla-k2-item-as-object-on-category-page)